# An underwater farm that needed helium

Tags: story-identification, food

I read that story at lest 30 years ago, maybe more.

I don't think it was a full-length novel, but it was not a very short story either.

There was an underwater farm that raised animals for food for the general population who lived on the surface. It was **definitely not** a generally underwater civilisation, just a farm. Maybe not the only farm in all the oceans, but there were many more "surface people" than deep-water farmers.

I am afraid they raised sea mammals, not fish. Dolphins or porpoises or dugongs or manatees, I don't remember. Not whales, though. Still not very politically correct, now.

Anyway, I remember very little. The main point of the story was, since the farm was very deep, they could not use nitrogen. They needed helium. Oxygen was not a problem, they had a lot of energy to extract it from water. But helium is rare. They recycled it as much as possible but there was a steady unavoidable seepage. And the surface people did not want to give them enough helium.

I don't remember much but at the end the deep-sea dwellers managed to get their own helium supplies and won the upper hand on the surface people who wanted to pressure them.

---

Edit

I **think** I remember that the surface people had space travel, at least within the solar system.

Definitely no aliens, but maybe human space settlers. On the Moon, on Mars, on asteroids... or just artificial space stations.

It is possible that it was the spacers who eventually came to help the deep-sea people, they had access to a lot of helium up there.

But it may well be a false memory.

---

Second Edit

As per comments by a) beichst and b) Moriarty

a) There are many similarities with *Crisis on Conshelf 10* by Monica Hughes

But I don't remember "Gillers", humans who could breathe in water. Also the **main** protagonist was a lifelong deep-sea farmer, not someone recently arrived from the Moon.

I remember a dialogue of the main protagonist with a "surfacer", on the topic of quality. He was claiming that while "surface grown" beef came in various qualities, underwater farms were only selling to "surfacers" super-top quality. Now can one compare beef with fish ? Well, it **is** possible, it this was fish bioengineered to **taste** like meat. That **might well** be the cas in my story. But this point does not seem to be explicit in *Crisis on Conshelf 10*.

If fish in the latter book tastes like meat, **and** helium is more important than beichst claims, then the plot of *Crisis on Conshelf 10* converges to mine. The deep-sea farmers might well have been **on the verge** of rebellion because of the stinginess of the "surfacers", and help from the Moon on the specific topic of helium might have avoided violence. After all, I might have forgotten the "Gillers".

I know I can have false memories. It is possible that the "GIllers" are a false absence of memories.

But two things I am positive of :

- the crucial importance of helium
- the "super-top" quality of sea-produced food, so it had at least to **taste** like meat, but bio-engineered fish is indeed a possibility.

b) I was aware when I first posted of the plot similarity with Asimov's "The Martian Way". I seriously considered mentioning this similarity, but decided against. Maybe I should have.

However, the crucial point in "The Martian Way" is that the Martians dit it **all by themselves**.  In this story, I have a doubt : did the deep-sea dwellers solve their helium problem completely **by themselves** "à la Martian", or was the alliance with "Spacers" essential in bypassing the stinginess of the "surfacers" ? That would make a significant difference with "The Martian Way".

Comment: What was the helium used for?

Comment: Do you remember anything about the plot?  Submarines?  Sea monsters?

Comment: @DoscoJones At very high pressure, nitrogen becomes toxic. One has to use helium  instead. In fact one can use hydrogen instead (Hydrox), which would have solved the problem. But maybe it was not well-known when the author wrote this book, or he just did not care,  he wanted a good story. When I read it, the idea of Hydrox did not occur to me. Since that time, I found out it is **not** a dangerously explosive mixture if the proportion of oxygen is very small, which is what is **needed** for very deep diving.

Comment: @DoscoJones No sea monsters. Submarines, probably. I mean, they had to go to the surface and back, and maybe the farm was large, and maybe there were more than one farm, and they travelled from one to the other. But the subs were just a mean of transportation, they did not represent a plot topic. What I **think** I remember, is that the surface people had space travel, at least within the solar system. Definitely no aliens, but maybe human space settlers. On the Moon, on Mars, on asteroids... But it may well be a false memory.

Comment: @Alfred.  Parts of this remind me of the 1975 novel Crisis on Conshelf 10 by Monica Hughes.  E.g. undersea farming, contact/aid from lunar settler, conflict with surface, etc.  There is also a scene reference Heliox use.  The parts that don't match are that in the Hughe's novel the farming is of fish. Too, the conflict is over separatist sea dwellers, not helium.   However, given some of the plot similarities is it possible you might have conflated two separate novels into one memory?

Comment: @beichst I am not convinced. I don't remember a young man from the Moon sent to the underwater farm. Nor modified humans able to breathe in water.  Of course it was long ago, I might have some false memories. I do remember that helium was a problem. But it is true that an alliance between the deep-sea people and settlers on the Moon looks common. Lack of helium did stir separatist feeling for the sea dwellers, yes. It might be farming fish, after all, though I think I remember it was meat,  meat of sea mammals... Or maybe not.. ?

Comment: Per my previous comment, the book described by the OP sounds like an exact cross between Asimov's "The Martian Way" and Willard Price's "Diving Adventure". The latter had the underwater farm with helium (but wasn't SF and had no helium shortage or stingy surface dwellers). The former was SF and had the scarce resource, with supply only available by stingy Earthers.

Comment: @Moriarty I was quite aware of the similarity with Asimov's "The Martian Way". But I clearly remember **farming for food**. If not for mammals, that might just possibly be a false memory, at least for fish. There was a dialogue with a "surfacer" about quality. The deep-sea protagonist arguing that compared to beef  sold by surface farms that came in several qualities, they were only selling super-top quality. That does not fit what I found about "Diving Adventure".

Comment: @skyjack I looked for *Medusa's Children" on Goodreads. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/883689.Medusa_s_Children The readers review really do not match my memories. What Meghan McGinnis and Mark Horne allude to is totally absent from what I remember. And I **would** have remembered it. Begum Keskin, too, alludes to the unspeakable LOL

Comment: There are some similarities with Arthur C. Clarke's "The Deep Range" but the Q is very specific about the farmed animals being not whales and that the sub-sea settlements were permanent. Helium is mentioned but only as a one-off deep-diving requirement not a continuous requirement. So probably not that...

Comment: @AdamT I read the synopsis of "The Deep Range" on Wikipedia. Indeed, it does not match my memories. In particlar, "surfacers" are not so interested in submarine food. It is a plus, not a necessity.

Comment: @beichst If you turn your comment into an answer, I would **not** accept it, unless you bring new elements to convince me. I still hope for a more convincing proposal. But unless someone else actually proposes a better answer, before that, I would give you the bonus during the "grace period" that follows the 7 days of the bonus "proper", for offering the closest answer of all proposed in comments.  So that my rep points wouldn't be lost for everyone.

Comment: @Alfred.  Thank you for the generous offer.  Unfortunately I don't really have much additional that I think I could be added to support the suggestion.  The helium factor was  simply not that critical of a plot point.  Too, it was definitely fish that were being farmed, not other meat animals.  Sorry.

Comment: @beichst You missed my point. If you **do** provide extra info, for instance that the fish was modified to taste like meat, I would **accept** your answer during the  validity of the bonus and **you'd get 50 for the bonus plus 15 for an accepted answer.**  If someone else posts a better answer first, he'll get them. But if you just write your comment as an answer, unconvincing as it is,  **if nobody does better than you,** I can still wait for the bonus validity to expire, and then "manually" award the bonus to you (I have only 24h hours to do so, grace period) but you won't get the 15 points.

Comment: I found an e-book of *Crisis on Conshelf Ten* and it doesn't mention helium at all.

Comment: @Alfred How could they raise (air breathing) sea mammals if the depth is so great the farm workers need helium to breath?

Comment: @john Rennie.  Thanks for checking on this.  I checked out an online copy from the library and I think you are correct. I could not find helium referenced either. I thought I remembered a scene in Crisis in which the MC had to wear a translator because of breathing an OxyHelium mix. However searching through it, I appear to have made a mistake and mixed two different books.  Alfred this is even more reason why I think I should decline to put it as a formal answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie Do you know how deep air-breathing sperm whale can dive ?

Comment: @JohnRennie I did say they were not raising whales. But the southern elephant seal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_elephant_seal can dive deeper than 3000 feet. Also, it is SF. They might raise bio-engineered seals. Or as I suggested, bio-engineered fish that taste like mammalian meat. But apparently my story is **not** "Crisis.."

Comment: @beichst Provided I "manually" grant the bonus, during the short grace period that follows the normal validity of the bonus, to an interesting answer that just is not the one I am looking for, I keep the possibility, indefinitely, to accept the good answer, if it ever is proposed. You hurt noone by posting your answer. I'll wait till the last minute, well, till the last hour, in case the good answer arrives just in time. Too bad to let 50 rep be lost ! As a matter of fact, the grace period has **just** started. You have 23h to post your answer, after that it will be too late

Comment: A final possibility could be "City under the sea" by Kenneth Bulmer. It involves helium, and fish engineered to taste like chicken, but otherwise doesn't fit very well.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I just looked at the synopsis. Indeed, it does not fit. My deep-sea farmers are normal people, they can perfectly go out (probably after appropriate stays at intermediate depths to avoid "bends", even with helium instead of nitrogen) and down again. Still, if you make this an answer, to avoid the 50 reps being lost uselessly, **if** beichst does not post **his answer**, which is closer, yours will be the only one to give manually the bonus to... ;)

Comment: @JohnRennie Hi ! You commented you have an e-book on "Crisis.." and it does not mention helium. Could you please check whether there is in this e-book a scene between a deep-sea guy and a "surfacer" about "surface-raised" beef meat that can be higher or lower grade (or quality, or some other word?) while the food he provides from the sea is **always** highest grade ? If this scene exists, maybe the helium thing is a false memory and "Crisis.." is indeed my story.

Comment: @Alfred The words *meat*, *beef* and *grade* do not appear in *Crisis on Conshelf Ten*.

Comment: @JohnRennie What about quality ? I am french, I cannot imagine all possible words that could be used in such a discussion, where the sea-farmer wants to emphasise how much the food he sells is better than what is grown on the surface. But indeed, if neither meat nor beef appear, this discussion really is not there, so my book is definitely not "Crisis.." and the helium is **not** a false memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very partial answer, but in the absence of anything better I will put it forward anyway.

Kenneth Bulmer's 1957 novel "[City Under the Sea](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4286)" concerns the development of undersea communities, run by highly unscrupulous corporations, for "the intense cultivation or sea-weeds and adapted marine plants, the solid shoals of fish herded about the sea like cattle", as well as mineral and oil extraction. Rather than sea mammals, however, they concentrated on raising fish:

> Processed fish and fish-products were on every table — and few
> housewives could be certain that what they were cooking had once had
> the unmistakable tang of fish

At several points people are shown eating the fish meat and noting how it is practically indistinguishable from chicken. A point of similarity with the question is that the story emphasises the importance of helium as a diving gas, and, for example, explains the practical problems of speaking intelligibly in an atmosphere with a high helium content. There seems to be no particular shortage of the gas however, or any conflict related to it.

There are indeed human space settlers, who have settled the Moon and have the ambition of settling Saturn's moons, and there is a competition for funding with the undersea people. The protagonist is a Space Force officer, Commander Jeremy Dodge, who is invited to visit the undersea community. The invitation is a ruse however, and he is press-ganged into the enslaved workforce who have been surgically altered to have gills to breathe seawater directly, so-called "menfish". The rest of the novel deal with the discovery of alien life in a nearby ocean trench, and how undersea and space expertise must combine to deal with it.

So this matches on undersea farming, helium, and interaction with spacefarers. Unfortunately it does not match on helium shortages, water-breathing humans, or a fight for freedom against the surface folk.

Comment: This is not my book, and even farther than "Crisis.." But stilll an interesting effort. Unless beichst posts his suggestion as an answer, or unless a third party posts an **even better one** before that time, I'll manually give the bonus to you without accepting your answer shortly before the dealine, 6:00PM  in France, 5:00 UT

Comment: The deadline was still a bit later but I have to run. Too bad for latecomers ! Kudos to you !